# What would an algorithm that can target different devices be called?

Tags: audio

I'm developing an audio filtering algorithm that can be run in different scenarios, e.g as embedded firmware on DSP Codec/Core, as a software library, or as a cloud service. Effectively, it can target solutions for hardware, software, and services - but I realize there are semantics and overlap here.

I'm struggling to identify a category to describe this breadth of approach.

An analogous question, by way of example, would be what would I call a software library that can run on Windows, Linux, and macOS or Intel, Arm, etc. The answer would be a cross-platform software.

Can anyone help?

Edit 1:

following on from a comment below, it is useful to focus on the 'portable' nature and it being loosely-coupled to any architecture, device or platform.

Comment: "portable between different hardware architectures", maybe?

Comment: thanks @MarcusMüller - it;s not what I'm looking for, but the portable aspect is close so thanks for trying!

Comment: Platform agnostic

Comment: thanks for your thought @DanBoschen - the problem with the word platform is that it tends to be focused on simlar devices, like PCs or Game consoles. Whereas what I'm seeking is a category that encapsulates something more universal.to any form of computing. A big ask, I know!.

Comment: Core technology?

Comment: @garrilla I must admit my interpretation of "different platforms" is definitely not about similar, but actually different kinds of devices.

Comment: hi @MarcusMüllerwould you say that cross-platform would extend from firmware implementation, through software (libraries and drivers) and up to services?